# Wrong number of cpus in system monitor

Tags: cpu, system-monitor

I am running Ubuntu 16.04. I have two Intel Xeon E5-2683 V4 CPUs. Each CPU has 16 cores and 2 threads per core, but the system monitor only shows 58 processors.   Why does the system monitor only show 58 processors?

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://askubuntu.com/questions/636452/ubuntu-not-recognizing-all-cpu-cores

Comment: What number does `grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l` produce?

Comment: The number is 64.

Answer (score 0):

If it makes you feel any better I also get 58 CPUs in system monitor on a 4x24-core system :) But

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Showed 192 CPUs. Then i decided to check perf. So i installed

```
sudo apt install sysbench
```

Then i ran

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=200000 --num-threads=200 run
```

It reported total time: 4.81s

Then i ran

```
sysbench --test=cpu --cpu-max-prime=200000 --num-threads=100 run
```

It reported total time: 7.49s

Then i used info from this link to double check utilization/CPU temps:
[How do I get the CPU temperature?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15832/how-do-i-get-the-cpu-temperature)

So it appears that the system does have and use more than 100 cores even though the system monitor shows 58.